# How to position water mesh filters?

Tags: watering

Is it important for at what angle I mount a mesh water filter? What positions are acceptable?
[image: mesh-filter-water]

Details: this is connected to urban potable water tap from in an area with medium hardness water. The reason for putting is because I have a dripline and mini drippers and I want to avoid clogging.

My intent is to mount it under the tap, so the flow direction would be from up to down. I suspect it does not matter how I mount it as long I can access it for cleaning.

Comment: @J.Chomel I bought this for gardening! It is for gardening, driplines do require them.

Comment: Ok sorry, then you should add some context to your question: how dirty is the water you want to filter? What's in it? gravel? sand? bacteria? No arm done, I retracted my Close vote.